# Backlash error. Pandas filter dataframe using dynamic query string.

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, query-string

**Hi all,
The problem is related to the Python backlash error.
I am creating a dynamic query string for filtering in pandas.
The code  is:**

```
       filters = dict(wlbWellType=['EXPLORATION'])
       query_string = ''
       index = 0
       for (k,v) in filters.iteritems():
          for i in v:
              if (index == 0):
                  query_string += '"{}"'.format((k) + ' == '+"'{}'".format(i)) 
              else:
              query_string += ' & ' '"{}"'.format((k) + ' == ' + 
              "'{}'".format(i))
             index += 1
```

If I do "print query_string" the output I got is

```
             "wlbWellType == 'EXPLORATION'"
```

If I do "query_string" the output I got is

```
             '"wlbWellType == \'EXPLORATION\'"'
```

I want

```
             "wlbWellType == 'EXPLORATION'"
```

as the output without using print statement. Seems there is an error related to backlash.

The query_string output will then be used as:

```
            df.query(query_string)
```

Can anyone please help me with the above problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you post a small reproducible sample of `filters` DF/Series?

Comment: and the error I got is :
                'the label ["wlbWellType == \'EXPLORATION\'"] is not in the [index]'

Comment: @MaxU- I got an error when I use it in DF. The error is posted in the comment above.

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own helper function (similar to what you're trying now but making use of `**kwargs`) and use the `@varname` syntax as the value placeholder.

```
def my_filter(df, **kwargs):
    qs = ' & '.join('{0} == @{0}'.format(k) for k in kwargs)
    return df.query(qs, local_dict=kwargs)
```

Then use as follows:

```
new_df = my_filter(df, wlbWellType='EXPLORATION', otherColumn='SOMETHING')
```

This method is safer than manually escaping values as the `@varname` syntax will do that appropriately for you depending on the value's type.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you are wrapping your key in python format string ( "'{}'".format ) as well. Try this  solution:

```
query_string = ""
index = 0
for (k,v) in filters.iteritems():
  for i in v:
    if (index == 0):
      query_string += str(k) + " == " + "'{}'".format(i)
    else:
      query_string += " & " + str(k) + " == " + "'{}'".format(i)
  index += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following approach:

```
In [44]: filters
Out[44]:
           col          val
0  wlbWellType  EXPLORATION
1          bbb          BBB

In [45]: qry = filters['col'].add(' == "').add(filters['val']).add('"').str.cat(sep=' & ')

In [46]: print(qry)
wlbWellType == "EXPLORATION" & bbb == "BBB"
```

slightly different syntax:

```
In [50]: qry = (filters['col'] + ' == "' + filters['val'] + '"').str.cat(sep=' & ')

In [51]: qry
Out[51]: 'wlbWellType == "EXPLORATION" & bbb == "BBB"'
```