# Python: join string list if else oneliner

Tags: python, string, pandas

Working with Pandas, I have to rewrite queries implemented as a `dict`:

```
query = {"height": 175}
```

The key is the attribute for the query and the value could be a scalar or iterable.
In the first part I check if the value is `not NaN and scalar`.
If this condition holds I write the query expression with the `==` symbol, but else if the value is `Iterable` I would need to write the expression with the `in` keyword.
This is the actual code that I need to fix in order to work also with Iterables.

```
import numpy as np
from collections import Iterable


def query_dict_to_expr(query: dict) -> str:
    expr = " and ".join(["{} == {}"
                        .format(k, v) for k, v in query.items()
                         if (not np.isnan(v)
                             and np.isscalar(v))
                         else "{} in @v".format(k) if isinstance(v, Iterable)
                         ]
                        )
    return expr
```

but I got invalid syntax in correspondence with the `else` statement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [if/else in Python's list comprehension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4260280/if-else-in-pythons-list-comprehension)

Comment: `else "{} in @v".format(k) if isinstance(v, Iterable)`. Why the second `if` there?

Comment: If you can't work out how to write a comprehension, then write it out as a loop, that will do no harm unless performance is absolutely critical and will be more readable for you no doubt

Comment: to check if the value is Iterable. It has to be an else if statement.

Comment: You can't put `if` again after the `else`. The list comprehension can't get it is a nested if/else clause.

Comment: @Juan not sure if it helps, but you may be able to re-use something from an [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45711055/backlash-error-pandas-filter-dataframe-using-dynamic-query-string/45711693#45711693) of mine... (swapping the == with `in` depending on type) - so you're always using the `@` syntax...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you don't need to check the type:

```
In [47]: query
Out[47]: {'height': 175, 'lst_col': [1, 2, 3]}

In [48]: ' and '.join(['{} == {}'.format(k,v) for k,v in query.items()])
Out[48]: 'height == 175 and lst_col == [1, 2, 3]'
```

Demo:

```
In [53]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(5, size=(5,3)), columns=list('abc'))

In [54]: df
Out[54]:
   a  b  c
0  0  0  3
1  4  2  4
2  2  2  3
3  0  1  0
4  0  4  1

In [55]: query = {"a": 0, 'b':[0,4]}

In [56]: q = ' and '.join(['{} == {}'.format(k,v) for k,v in query.items()])

In [57]: q
Out[57]: 'a == 0 and b == [0, 4]'

In [58]: df.query(q)
Out[58]:
   a  b  c
0  0  0  3
4  0  4  1
```

Answer (score 1):

You misplaces the `if/else` in the comprehension. If you put the `if` after the `for`, like `f(x) for x in iterable if g(x)`, this will filter the elements of the iterable (and can not be combined with an `else`). Instead, you want to keep all the elements, i.e. use `f(x) for x in iterable` where `f(x)` just happens to be a ternary expression, i.e. in the form `a(x) if c(x) else b(x)`.

Instead, try like this (simplified non-numpy example):

```
>>> query = {"foo": 42, "bar": [1,2,3]}  
>>> " and ".join(["{} == {}".format(k, v)
                  if not isinstance(v, list)
                  else "{} in {}".format(k, v)
                  for k, v in query.items()])
'foo == 42 and bar in [1, 2, 3]'
```